# How to set Processing image for server side processing in jquery datatables

Tags: datatables

I'm working on jquery **datatables grid**, I have to pass more than **30000 rows** in my grid I'm using json.parse to get the rows, It takes plenty of time and I have to set processing image for loading time.

Here is my client side code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            loaddata();
        });
        function loaddata() {
            var rows;
          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "RMTS_Edit_View.aspx/LoadSFHGrid",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(r) {
                    var data = r.d.split("~")[0],
                            record = r.d.split("~")[1];
                    if (record == 'Y') {
                        rows = JSON.parse(data);
                        var table = $("#tblRMTSViewEdit tbody")
                        $.each(rows, function(index, rows) {
                            table += "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='chkBoxHelp" + (index + 1) + "' onclick='chkbox(" + (index + 1) + ");'/></td><td>" + (index + 1) + "</td><td>" + rows.MaterialCode + "</td><td>" + rows.MaterialDescription + "</td><td>" + rows.HSNCode + "</td><td>" + rows.IGST_TaxRate + "</td><td>" + rows.CGST_TaxRate + "</td><td>" + rows.SGST_TaxRate + "</td><td>" + (rows.MaterialType) + "</td><td>" + rows.Plant_Code + "</td></tr>";
                        });
                        $("#tblRMTSViewEdit tbody").html(table);
                        $("#tblRMTSViewEdit").dataTable({
                            "bSort": true,
                            "ServerSide": true,
                            "deferRender": true,
                            //"searching": true,
                            "Processing": true,
                            "scrollX": true,
                            "scrollY": true,
                            "scrollY": '40vh',
                            "lengthMenu": [[100, 200, 500, -1], [100, 200, 500, "All"]]
                        });
                        $('#tblRMTSViewEdit_filter').addClass("");
                        $('#tblRMTSViewEdit_filter').addClass("dataTables_filter pull-right");
                        $('#tblRMTSViewEdit_paginate').addClass("dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pull-right");
                    }
                },

                failure: function(r) {
                    alert("");
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: This is not much help in terms of your initial question, but why aren't you using DataTables to populate your table for you?

Comment: My requirement is to do in jquery datatables, and I've to do pagination edit add and as well as search through out my grid.

Comment: Even so, @Gowtham server-side processing should do what you need, without the huge delay - and even if you're reticent about writing backend code (or you don't have access) you can still get DataTable to populate the table with it's built in ajax processing - perhaps you could provide a sample of your data?